# PostSharp logging smart tag unavailable

Tags: postsharp

I'm just getting started with PostSharp. For some reason I'm not seeing the logging smart tag - the only option I have is adding "architecture constraints".

Also I'm not seeing the smart tag on private methods.

What may be the problem?

**UPDATE**

Diagnostics output:

```
devenv.exe Information: 0 : OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Smart tag: restart quiet period.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Ignoring this tick because it's too early.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Smart tag: OnTick
devenv.exe Information: 0 : AddAspectsSmartTagger.UpdateCurrentCodeElement
devenv.exe Information: 0 : AddAspectsSmartTagger.GetTag
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Architecture.ComponentInternalConstraintTypeAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Architecture.InternalImplementConstraintAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.AggregatableAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.ChildAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.DisposableAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.EditableObjectAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.ParentAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.RecordableAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.ReferenceAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.CreditCardQuickAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.EmailAddressQuickAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.GreaterThanQuickAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.LessThanQuickAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.NotEmptyQuickAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.NotNullQuickAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.PhoneQuickAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.PositiveQuickAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.RangeQuickAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.RequiredQuickAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.StrictlyPositiveQuickAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.UrlQuickAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Threading.ApplyThreadingModelAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Threading.DeadlockDetectionAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Architecture.AddConstraintAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 :   eligible.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Architecture.ComponentInternalConstraintAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Architecture.InternalConstraintAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 :   eligible.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Architecture.ProtectedConstraintAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 :   eligible.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Threading.UpgradeableReaderLockAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 :   not eligible because of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Filters.PackageCompatibilityFilter does not match.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Diagnostics.LogAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 :   not eligible because of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Filters.PackageCompatibilityFilter does not match.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Domain.NotifyPropertyChangedAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Threading.BackgroundMethodAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 :   not eligible because of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Filters.PackageCompatibilityFilter does not match.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Threading.DispatchedAttribute.
devenv.exe Information: 0 :   not eligible because of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Filters.PackageCompatibilityFilter does not match.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Threading.ObserverLockAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 :   not eligible because of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Filters.PackageCompatibilityFilter does not match.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Threading.ReaderLockAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 :   not eligible because of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Filters.PackageCompatibilityFilter does not match.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Threading.WriterLockAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 :   not eligible because of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Filters.PackageCompatibilityFilter does not match.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Architecture.ComponentInternalConstraintTypeAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Architecture.InternalImplementConstraintAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Architecture.ComponentInternalConstraintAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Architecture.InternalConstraintAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 :   eligible.
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Determining eligibility of PostSharp.VisualStudio.Services.QuickAction.Actions.Architecture.ProtectedConstraintAction.
devenv.exe Information: 0 :   eligible.
devenv.exe Information: 0 :   found 1 actions
```

The part that causing trouble says ***not eligible because of PackageCompatibilityFilter does not match***. What does it mean?

**UPDATE 2**
I'm targeting .NET 3.5; If I switch to .NET 4.5 the logging becomes available. Is this a limitation of PostSharp?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio and PostSharp are you using?

Comment: PostSharp 4.0.43; Visual Studio 2013. I have to say that I'm getting this issue only with my dll. Creating a console application from scratch works fine.

Comment: Switching to .NET 4.5 enables the logging option. However I need to target .NET 3.5; Is this a limitation of PostSharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostSharp Diagnostics Pattern Library is not supported on .NET 3.5. The same goes for other Pattern Libraries.

You would have to use PostSharp itself (Aspect Framework) to implement similar logic.